# Remove whitespace from image in Android Studio

Tags: android, image, android-studio, android-layout, imageview

[image]

As one can see in the above image there is a lot of white space around the small image in this ImageView layout. How do I remove the white space and make the image view the same size as the actual image it is displaying? If I make the ImageView smaller, it makes the view smaller but still has white space around the image itself. How do I remove it?

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

add this XML Attribute to the image view declaration:
`adjustViewBounds="true"`

For example, your `ImageView` XML would look like this:

```
<ImageView
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to do

```
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

in image view.

In addition to that, u can do below things for good practices

you can use `ImageView.ScaleType(FIT_XY)` but this will change ration of your image and x,y axis expands independently fill your image view

u need to add  `android:scaleType="fitXY"` in xml file image view for it.

you can use `ImageView.ScaleType(FIT_CENTER)` it will keep ration and expan x,y until one fill your image view

u need to add  `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` in xml file image view for it.

you can find all of the options by navigating this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType

Answer (score 0):

I've researched some fixes and none of them worked. What did work was changing from a mipmap to a drawable image. I'm getting other errors, but at least the original problem has been fixed.